# JQuery and links - strange situation

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click, handler

some text link1

```
<a href="http://anotherlink.com">link2</a>
```

And JQuery code:

```
$('#inner a').click(function(){
   console.log( 'achtung' );
});
```

But when I click at **link1**, click-handler doesn't call.

And in another situation:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   console.log( 'achtung' );
});
```

And when I click at **link2**, handler calls, but **link1** is still unworking.

Could you explain me: why?

---

Here is more code:

```
 <div id="text-wrapper">
    <div id="text">
       <div id="content_close">close</div>
       <div id="inner">
       <!--Here will be content--> <br />               
    </div>
    ...
 </div>
```

And content is loaded by ajax into inner-block.

---

My problem was in that I'm loading content with links dynamically, so, when jquery code runs, the page could doesn't content my link. So I have to use live-function:

```
$('#inner a').live( 'click', function(){ alert('achtung'); } );
```

Thanks all, problem is solved.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with any of that code (though I note you're allowing the link addresses to still be followed after the handler runs, which seems deliberate).  Best guess: something's wrong with the markup surrounding #inner.  Does the page validate?

Comment: Are you sure that both chunks of code actually ran?  Essentially, this code looks perfectly fine.  I would recommend trying to run this in isolation, and make sure you don't have something interfering with this.

Comment: Where is this code included in your page - the footer, the header, or an external file?

Comment: That might be your problem -- put the code in a $(document).ready() block.

Answer (score 2):

Is your jQuery code wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` ?

If you are not waiting for the DOM to be ready, it is possible that jQuery cannot find `#inner`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#inner a').click(function(){
        console.log( 'achtung' );
    });
});
```

Comment: It is good practice to put all Javascript at the end of the page if possible. The reason for this is because browsers go into synchronous mode when they encounter JS. By placing the code at the end of the page, the content can display much faster, giving the user the impression that the page is loading much faster. Wrapping the code in a doc.ready function is not necessary unless one assumes the person will click the link as soon as they see it.

Comment: If your Javascript is at the end of your page, then waiting for the DOM to be ready cost you nothing except that you protect yourself against odd/strange/weird/bizarre browser bugs.

Answer (score 1):

When I change

```
 console.log( 'achtung' );
```

to

```
 alert( 'achtung' );
```

It works for me as expected.

Perhaps your console is acting wonky, or whatever you're using to view it isn't working properly?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="inner">some text <a href="#contacts">link1</a></div>
<p><a href="http://anotherlink.com">link2</a> <script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$('#inner a').click(function(){
   alert( 'achtung' );
});
/*]]>*/
</script></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing happens. I also tried to set breakpoint in FireBug. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I added my full test code. I'm also running FF 3.5.3 on Unbuntu. What are you running?

Comment: You might also try your code using another browser and/or turn off all your extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, try putting a "return;" or "debugger;" as the last line of your function.  I'm wondering if hitting the link is causing the console to be cleared.

Comment: Nothing happens. But when I click at links in inner, FireBug console is 'jump' up in a few seconds and then come back.

Comment: Sounds like the jquery click event is not getting bound to the link.  Try adding an id to the link and using it to select the anchor element, and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `inner` ID unique in the page?

You could try to query it in Firebug using `document.getElementById("inner")` and see if the return DOM node is the one you expect (hover the result in Firebug, il will hilight the DOM node in your page).

Comment: I'm out of options for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this.
The HTML or just the NODE has to be loaded. To accomplish this you have to check whether your page is loaded or execute the JavaScript after the DOM is fully updated.

if you specify your javascript in your `<head>` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#inner a').click(function(){
    console.log( 'achtung' );
  });
</script>
```

It will execute when it is read. The rest of the HTML isn't loaded in the DOM so the '#inner a' element cannot be found by JavaScript.
There are several ways to check if you page is loaded

```
// simplest form, not the best (without jQuery)
window.onload = function () {
  // search for the node with jQuery
  $('#inner a').click(function(){
    alert( 'achtung' );
  });
}

// jQuery form, best
$(document).ready(function () {
  // search for the node with jQuery
  $('#inner a').click(function(){
    alert( 'achtung' );
  });
});

// smallest jQuery from, also best
$(function () {
  // search for the node with jQuery
  $('#inner a').click(function(){
    alert( 'achtung' );
  });
});
```

The other way is to place inline JavaScript after the domnode

```
<div id="inner">
  <a href="/test.html">link1</a>
</div>
<a href="/test2.html">link2</a>`
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  $('#inner a').click(function(){
    alert( 'achtung' );
  });
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```